# Qt - How to Draw an Icon Image to a QListWidgetItem

Tags: qt4, qpainter, qlistwidget, qpixmap, qlist

I have QListWidget, in that I had added the items.  i had made the ***QListWidgetItems to scroll from right to left in a QWidget.*** Now i want to ***add a Icon image before every item*** that is Scrolling in the QWidget. How to draw an Icon image in a QWidget ? Plz help me with your Solutions. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not trying QListWidgetItem::setIcon( QIcon & ) ?

Use QListWidgetItem * QListWidget::item ( int row ) iterating from 0 to  QListWidget::count()
for setting to all existing items in QListWidget.